# npm scripts won't execute

Tags: node.js, web, npm, npm-scripts

I have set up a few projects with npm, and so far, running `'npm start'` in the terminal, or using the npm scripts panel in the VSCode explorer would run and start my apps.

However, the scripts simply don't seem to run anymore, I did no change to the project nor to the Node in my machine, and the problem isn't with my code, as starting my Vue app through the Vue User Interface will work just fine.

In the detail of what happens: I run `npm start` (which is defined in package.json), the terminal will start the task, and then end with no explanation.

If anyone knows what the purpose of this could be...

[terminal print upon executing npm script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpflP.png)

[package.json print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMb3Q.png)

Comment: You should share your index.js

Comment: Yes, turns out the problem was the npm ignore-scritps setting, thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you run npm start it will run according to the package.json file. In this case it will run "electron ." and I am not sure what that is supposed to do.

An example of a start script would be:

```
start: "npm run build && node server.js"
```

Then it will run that script when you run "npm start".

Comment: ```build``` script has not been defined at above ```package.json``` How can it be executed??